# How to execute a Batchfile in a folder, by dropping the folder on the file

Tags: batch-file

I have a small batch file that executes a few simple lines of code.

It works perfectly fine when I put it **in** the Folder and execute it.

However the file should be located on level above it and be able to get executed by having the folder being droped on to it.

When I currently drop the folder on to it, it just executes the code as if I would just double click it. However it should behave as if the file was located inside the folder.

```
@echo off

for %%a in (*.*) do @echo %%~na >> filenames.txt
)

pause
```

How would I do that?

I don't want to apply it to every folder just the one chosen by dropping it onto the file.

I want to generate a file from all the filenames inside the Folder.

which will then be compared to an other file created from an other folder.

```
@echo off
echo new additions > test3.txt
findstr /vixg:shots.txt shots2.txt >> test3.txt
echo removed >> test3.txt
findstr /vixg:shots2.txt shots.txt >> test3.txt
```

I assume I can|t automate the comparison, by dropping two folders onto the file, can I?

Comment: So.. how about posting the code of your batch file so we can see it and actually help you?

Comment: thanks for the imput

Comment: When dropping elements on another batch/script/exe they get passed as command line arguments, receivable in batch with `%1` to `%9` (or as %1 and looped with a [shift](http://ss64.com/nt/shift.html) in between). So it **is** possible, but you show fixed file names and expect ever changing file/folder names to be accessed how?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you want, but I am assuming you want to match `shots.txt` which is in `folder1` with `shots2.txt` in `folder2`. Something like this should work if that is the case:

```
@echo off
echo new additions > test3.txt
if exist "%1\shots.txt" (findstr /vixg:"%1\shots.txt" "%2\shots2.txt" >> test3.txt)
if exist "%2\shots.txt" (findstr /vixg:"%2\shots.txt" "%1\shots2.txt" >> test3.txt)
echo removed >> test3.txt
if exist "%1\shots2.txt" (findstr /vixg:"%1\shots2.txt" "%2\shots.txt" >> test3.txt)
if exist "%2\shots.txt" (findstr /vixg:"%2\shots2.txt" "%1\shots.txt" >> test3.txt)
```

You can then select 2 folders containing the files and drop them both onto the batch file.